# How to parse multiple object in json in javascript?

Tags: javascript, json

I have following json to be parsed and need to make different object

```js
var object={"statusCode": 200, "headers": {}, "body": "{\"statusColor\": {\"abc1\": \"green\", \"abc2\": \"red\", \"bcd11\": \"red\", \"bcd2\": \"green\", \"cde1\": \"green\", \"cde2\": \"red\", \"efg1\": \"red\", \"efg2\": \"red\", \"efg3\": \"red\"}, \"time\": 
{\"abc\": \"2020-02-03 11:41:40\", \"bcd\": \"2020-02-03 11:41:40\", \"cde\": \"2020-02-03 11:41:40\", \"efg\": \"2020-02-03 11:41:40\"}}"}

//Iam trying to get the seperate dict object for statusColor and time as below

var dict={}
dict=object
console.log("Status color is", dict.body['statusColor'])

#Out put is 'undefined'
```

Expected is :
statusColor= 'get dict of all status color' 
similarly for time
so what is the best approach to get the object dict from the multi json object?

Comment: are you sure that body is a valid JSON string?

Comment: I can see that body has `string` rather than an object. this json object is not valid - check in https://jsonlint.com/

Comment: parse the JSON string you have stored at the `body` property: `console.log("Status color is", JSON.parse(dict.body)['statusColor'])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to parse your JSON data in order to remove the escape slashes from the `body` object. The undefined error is because there is no key statusColor in the body object. If you log only the body object(if only this object is valid in JS) then you'll see the string

use `const parsedBody = JSON.parse(object.body)` and then try to refer to `parsedBody.statusColor`

Answer (score 1):

You have an invalid newline and you need to parse the body

Also

```
var dict={}
dict=object
```

is not copying the object, just creating another pointer to it

Working code:

```js
const object = {
  "statusCode": 200,
  "headers": {},
  "body": "{\"statusColor\": {\"abc1\": \"green\", \"abc2\": \"red\", \"bcd11\": \"red\", \"bcd2\": \"green\", \"cde1\": \"green\", \"cde2\": \"red\", \"efg1\": \"red\", \"efg2\": \"red\", \"efg3\": \"red\"}, \"time\":  {\"abc\": \"2020-02-03 11:41:40\", \"bcd\": \"2020-02-03 11:41:40\", \"cde\": \"2020-02-03 11:41:40\", \"efg\": \"2020-02-03 11:41:40\"}}"
}
const dict = JSON.parse(object.body)

console.log("Status color is", dict['statusColor'])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use JSON.parse() method to parse valid JSON string.

`var jsonObj = JSON.parse(object.body)`

```
 console.log(jsonObj.statusColor)
 console.log(jsonObj.time)

// output 
// statusColor: {abc1: "green", abc2: "red", bcd11: "red", bcd2: "green", cde1: "green", …}
// time: {abc: "2020-02-03 11:41:40", bcd: "2020-02-03 11:41:40", cde: "2020-02-03 11:41:40", efg: "2020-02-03 11:41:40"}
```

Comment: If you click the `[<>]` you can create a snippet like the other answers - not that it is needed anymore

Comment: Thank you @Rezwanul. This got worked. Actually i didn't check the return type of body which i assumed that it could be a dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

Try parsing the json first.

```
var object={"statusCode": 200, "headers": {}, "body": "{\"statusColor\": {\"abc1\": \"green\", \"abc2\": \"red\", \"bcd11\": \"red\", \"bcd2\": \"green\", \"cde1\": \"green\", \"cde2\": \"red\", \"efg1\": \"red\", \"efg2\": \"red\", \"efg3\": \"red\"}, \"time\": {\"abc\": \"2020-02-03 11:41:40\", \"bcd\": \"2020-02-03 11:41:40\", \"cde\": \"2020-02-03 11:41:40\", \"efg\": \"2020-02-03 11:41:40\"}}"};
 var dict = JSON.parse(object.body);
console.log(dict.statusColor);
```

Hope it helps.